# Mobile navigation on header top, but still position static

Tags: css, mobile, positioning, responsive-design

I have nav after heading for most devices. It look like this:

```
<header role="banner">
    <hgroup>
        <h1>
            <a href="/" rel="home">Site name</a>
        </h1>
        <h2>subname</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        </ul>
         <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

In portrait orientation diveces I want to place NAV to top and slide it down, after clicking MENU.
The problem is: How to put it on top in such a way, that after sliding down shifted contetnt (heading) down. As if the "nav" was before heading in DOM, but only for portrait orientated smartphones.
Absolute position placed nav over heading. I need both in the same flow.

Comment: I'd use position: fixed; with the assistance of some classes and media queries. Javascript as well, if needed to adjust margins.

Comment: Positio fixed not resolve the problem. I need effect similar to move <header>
    <nav />
    <hgroup />
</header>
After slide down navigation, heading should move down. But only for given resolutions. Media queries are not the problem, but the positioning and the elements flow is. :/